# Correct set notation with an indexed range

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of numbers

$$
A_c = \{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1\}
$$

Would it be correct to define this set more generally with the following notation (assuming $x_{max}$, $x_{min}$ and $n$ are defined)?

$$
A_c = \{x_\text{min} + (i-1) \cdot \frac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{n-1}\}_{i=1}^\text{n}
$$

Comment: I think you want $i$ to go until $n+1$.  Taking $n=4$, then when $i=n=4$ we get $0 + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$, yet we should get $1$

Comment: Well, for *that* set $n$ is defined to be specifically to be $4$ and $x_{min}=1$, $x_{max} = 5$ and you omitted the last term.

Comment: @fleablood if $x_{min}=1,x_{max}=5,$ and $n=4$ then $A_c = \{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @gd1035 .... or take $i$ instead of $i -1$ and let $i= 0....  4$

Comment: The effort it takes to get this right is an indication that it will be hard for your reader. A list like the one in your question, written with the (dot dot dot) ellipsis in the middle, will be easier to read and understand and just as "mathematical".

Comment: Yeah, you're right.   For some reason I was viewing the as $(x_{min} + (i-1))*\frac {...}n$.  I didn't get just how the OP was trying to generalize.

Comment: You can also define these types of sets by {x| x_min $\leq$ x $\leq$ x_max with integer step}. For example, {x | 0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 1, 4x $\in$ **Z**} defines the set you gave.

Comment: @EthanBolker  It depends.  If I saw  $\{5, 5.45, 5.90, 6.35, ...13.10, 13.55, 14]$ I wouldn't necessarily get that we are taking the interval $(5,14)$ and dividing into into 20ths, and taking the resulting 21 values.  Whereas $\{5 + k\frac {14-5}{20}|k=0...20\}$ might make that clear.

Comment: whoops sorry for the confusion: i rectified the denominator to $n-1$ to match the numerical example.

Comment: " i rectified the denominator to n−1 to match the numerical example"  I would n't have done that.  I'd extend the range from $i = 0....n$ and kept the denominator as $n$.

Comment: ... although I suppose $\{5, 5.45, 5.90, 6.35, ...13.10, 13.55, 14\}=\{5 + k\frac {14-5}{20}|k=0...20\}$ could be written as $\{x_0, .... x_{20}| x_0 = 5;x_{20}=14; x_i$ equally spaced$\}$.  That would be clear what the set is meant to *be*.  Might take a bit of arithmetic to get formula is $x_i = i*\frac {14-5}{20} + 5 = 14 - (20 - i)\frac {14-5}{20}$.

Comment: $\{.... (i-1)..(n-1)\}_{i=1}^n  = \{...... i.... (n-1)\}_{i=0}^{n-1} =\{.... i .... n'\}_{i=0}^{n'}$ when $n' = n-1$.  So don't have your index go from $1...n$ and have you notation be about $i-1$ and $n-1$.  Have your index go from $0... n$ and have your notation be  about $i$ and $n$ (which has been sensible redefined to the lower value.)

Comment: A = { n/4 : n = 0,1,2,3,4 }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a set that is $\{k, k + \frac{m-k}n, k + 2\frac {m-k}n, ...., k + (n- 1)\frac {m-k}n, m\}$ That can be written as

$\{k + i\frac {m-k}n| i\in \mathbb Z; 0\le i \le n\}$ which if we let $k = x_{min}$ and $m = x_{max}$ can be written as

$\{x_{min} + i*\frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}n\}_{i=0}^n$

By putting it as

$\{x_\text{min} + (i-1) \cdot \frac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{n}\}_{i=1}^\text{n}$

you are omitting the final term.

Comment: Many thanks! My original question was mostly to know if the notation was acceptable: If I assume correctly from your reply, both notations
$\{x_{min} + (i-1)\cdot\frac {x_{max}-x_{min}}{n-1}| i\in \mathbb Z; 1\le i \le n\}$ and 
$\{x_{min} + (i-1)\cdot\frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{n-1}\}_{i=1}^n$ are equivalent and correct? I.e. one can safely note the range of $i$ on the right side of the right bracket `}`?

Comment: I also took note of your advice regarding the $n-1$ vs $n$ notations. For practical reasons I prefer the heavier $n-1$, but might consider using your suggestion eventually.

Comment: Equivalent and correct but ridiculously hard to read.  Is there a reason you are insisting that are putting on cement galoshes and having your index absolutely *must* start at $1$ instead of $0$.  After all, if $m = n-1$ then $\{x_{min} + (i-1)\cdot\frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{n-1}\}_{i=1}^n=\{x_{min} + k\cdot\frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{m}\}_{k=0}^m$ and   ... Well.... it's a matter of taste... but I don't see any advantage to the former.

Comment: I agree with you: the readability is better in the second case. But the reason I'd keep the former is to avoid defining to additional variables $m=n-1$ and $k=i-1$, because `i` and `n` have already been defined and have a concrete meaning, and further it makes more sense in my context if `i` starts at 1, rather than 0.

Comment: Well, it that case....  Yeah, you can do whatever you want.